# One Class SVM for Anomaly DIagnosis

Tags: svm, outliers, anomaly-detection, one-class-classification

I have a dataset of normal points `Xtr` and I would like to fit a OneClass-SVM for anomaly detection purposes.

```
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM

#fit
ocsvm = OneClassSVM(nu=NU, kernel='rbf', gamma=GAMMA)
ocsvm.fit(X=Xtr)
```

Then, I would like to assess if every point in the test set Xts is an anomaly:

```
ocsvm.predict(Xts)
```

I would like also to determine a degree of anomaly by calculating the distance from the boundary:

```
ocsvm.decision_function(Xts)
```

Everything easy so far, but I would like to understand which feature contributes more to causing an anomaly?
How can I determine which of the `n` variables exceeded the limit of the normality curve defined by the one-class SVM during the training phase?

Should I manually calculate the distance for every `x in Xts` over all the coordinates (the `n` features) to understand the actual contribution of each feature?
Do there exist some libraries that already do it?

I have checked sklearn and pyod but it seems that this calculation is not implemented.